# Number of equivalence classes regarding congruency of symmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $K$.

Consider the set of symmetrical bilinear forms over $V$ with the equivalence relation of congruency.

Two bilinear forms are congruent $\iff$ there is an ordered basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $V$ such that the representing matrices of the bilinear forms are congruent.

The task is to find out the number of equivalence classes for fields $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Q}$.

However I struggle right at the beginning. I have found out that the equivalence relation also means that there exist two ordered bases $\mathfrak{B_1}, \mathfrak{B_2}$ such that the representative matrices of the bilinear forms are equal. Does that help me? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating this to a less abstract language.

If $n$ is finite the set of symmetric forms corresponds to the set of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

Two symmetric forms are equivalent if there is a basis that makes the two congruent.

There exists a $P$ such that $A = P^{-1} B P$

And since all symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

i.e.
$Q^{-1} A Q = P^{-1} B P = D$

Two matrices are equivalent if they have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: So the number of eq. classes only depends on the sets of possible eigenvalues? That would mean that for a field $K$ there are $|K|^n$ eq. classes for any of those fields? Sounds too good to be true.

Comment: You would need to account for multiplicities.  i.e. $\{1,1,2\}$ is equivalent to $\{1,2,1\}$ so $|K|^n$ is overstating it.

Comment: I come up with ${k+n-1\choose n}$

Comment: I thought you ment I would have to account for that $(1,1,1)$ is equivalent to $(2,2,2)$, I misunderstood.

Comment: I got it now too, I am amazed (and very suspicious) that you can solve all these problems at once (for all the fields), I suspected there would be differences between the fields (from how the task was presented).

Comment: @B.Swan congruence usually means, when $A,B$ are two symmetric matrices, that there is a nonsingular $P$ such that $P^T AP = B.$ The basic fact for the reals and rationals is Sylvester's Law of Inertia

Comment: This answer is partially wrong as it seems to conflate congruence of matrices, $P^TAP$, with equivalence, $P^{-1}AP$. True that symmetric matrices can be diagonalised (Gram-Schmidt) but then sometimes you can norm the diagonal and sometimes not, depending on arithmetic of the field (classes of squares/quadratic extensions), which for $\mathbb C$ boils down to the index (# of non-zero eigenvalues), and over the reals to signature (Sylvester), but not over the rationals. E.g. $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}$ are congruent over $\mathbb R$, but not over $\mathbb Q$, @WillJagy.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg If you are referring to my comment, I was not being particularly careful. Note that, on this site, often enough students give a symmetric integer matrix and want it diagonalised, while the eigenvalues are truly awful and could not be dealt with by hand. They are clearly being asked for nonsingular rational $P$ such that $P^T H P = D$ is diagonal, and have trouble with that. So I looked into this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  (and it is Lagrange's method, not Hermite).